# How to prevent data writes to ES index but allow alias updates

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to devise a process for re-indexing an Elasticsearch index with zero read downtime, rejecting write attempts until the process is done.

Given an original index and an alias pointing to it, the current flow is as follows:

1. Create a staging index
2. Make original index read-only
3. Copy data from original index to staging index
4. Make staging index read-only
5. Update the alias to point to the staging index
6. Re-create the original index
7. Copy data from staging index to original index
8. Update the alias to point to the original index

The problem is that either by closing an index or making it read-only with `index.blocks.read_only=true`, I can't update its alias.

Making the index read-only is important to make sure that anyone attempting to write data will get an error and handle the retry themselves.

Having the alias updated is important to make sure that anyone attempting to read data will get data without problems.

How can I make achieve this?

Comment: Please observe that this question differs from most elasticsearch zero-downtime questions because it's a requirement for me that writes will fail instead of be lost. Also, this is more specific: I want to know how to forbid data writes but allow metadata writes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there's a well documented option specifically for that:

> **[`index.blocks.write`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.5/index-modules.html)**
>
> Set to true to disable data write operations against the index. Unlike read_only, this setting does not affect metadata. For instance, you can close an index with a write block, but not an index with a read_only block.

For some reason I see it around much less than the more restrictive `read_only` option, but it fits perfectly here.